# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundExcxeption

Tags: java

This is the Client side of my multiple chat application. For some reason, the first line in the main function, where I tried to create a new chat client is giving me an Array Index Out of Bounds Exception. Please I would like to know If there is something that I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the whole code for the client side, but I have the issue on the first line after the main function.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class chatClient extends Frame implements Runnable {
    Socket soc; 
    TextField tf;
    TextArea ta;
    Button btnSend,btnClose;
    String sendTo;
    String LoginName;
    Thread t = null;
    DataOutputStream dout;
    DataInputStream din;

    chatClient(String LoginName,String chatwith) throws Exception {
        super(LoginName);
        this.LoginName = LoginName;
        sendTo = chatwith;
        tf = new TextField(50);
        ta = new TextArea(50,50);
        btnSend = new Button("Send");
        btnClose = new Button("Close");
        soc = new Socket("localhost",12342);

        din = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream()); 
        dout = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());     
        dout.writeUTF(LoginName);

        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    void setup()
    {
        setSize(600,400);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        add(ta);
        Panel p = new Panel();

        p.add(tf);
        p.add(btnSend);
        p.add(btnClose);
        add(p);
        show();     
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean action(Event e,Object o){
        if(e.arg.equals("Send")){
            try{
                dout.writeUTF(sendTo + " "  + "DATA" + " " + tf.getText().toString());          
                ta.append("\n" + LoginName + " Says:" + tf.getText().toString());   
                tf.setText("");
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
        else if(e.arg.equals("Close")){
            try{
                dout.writeUTF(LoginName + " LOGOUT");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return super.action(e,o);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        chatClient Client1 = new chatClient(args[0],args[1]);
        Client1.setup();                
    }   
    public void run(){      
        while(true){
            try{
                ta.append( "\n" + sendTo + " Says :" + din.readUTF());

            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: Did you forget to pass in command line arguments? At any rate it would be nice to check the size of `args` and notify the user if they forgot to specify some required arguments.

Comment: Are there specific things you would advise I try?

Answer (score 1):

The `args` variable is not of length two. This variable stores the command line arguments passed to the application.

You probably forgot to pass command line arguments. If you're using the command line, you specify them like so:

```
java chatClient "arg1" "arg2"
```

If you're using an IDE, like Eclipse to build and run the application, you will need to look up specific instructions for your IDE.

Comment: I was using Eclipse, but it didn't work. I have just tried running it from the terminal, but all to no avail.

Comment: C:\James\Workspace\ChatApp\bin> java chatServer

Comment: C:\James\Workspace\ChatApp\bin> java chatClient

Comment: @James As I said in my answer, you **have** to specify the arguments when running the command. Please re-read my answer...

Comment: I did read your answer, but it was a little bit confusing to me. How should I go about specifying the argument? Please be patient with me. I am still developing my coding skills. Thanks!

Comment: @James You need to change the command you are using to **java chatClient "arg1" "arg2"** . Whatever you put in the first set of speech marks is inserted into index 0 of **args** and whatever you put in the second set of speech marks is inserter into index 1 of **args**.